# storing string array to be used as symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With the goal of executing a `proc` as follows

```
validates :file, attached: true, content_type: ->(record){ record.parent.content_types: [:pdf, :txt, :rtf] }
```

The record `belongs_to :parent` and the parent has a column `content_types` which is created as follows:

```
t.string :content_types, array: true, default: [ 'pdf', 'txt', 'rtf' ]
```

If cast as follows, how can one verify the execution when an action invokes this validation

```
validates :file, attached: true, content_type: ->(record){ record.parent.content_types.map(&:to_sym) }
```

In otehr words, being uncertain of the syntax (it could be wrong) one would like to verify beforehand.

Comment: I don't think you need to convert it into symbols.